# Java Script on hover, on focus actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, focus

I'm weak about Coding on Java Script. I have some code , which makes an element visible. So it works well! But! When you move a lil bit your mouse it's being invisible for 0.5 sec - 1 sec . As I understand I need to make function with focus action? 
The element have to be visible whole time when mouse on focus,hover. <<< Whhat I need to do.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


    $('.fdw-background').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).animate({opacity:'1'});
        },
        function () {
            $(this).animate({opacity:'0'});
        }
    );


    $( ".fdw-background" ).hover(function(){
      $( ".fdw-background" ).focus(
        function () {
            $(this).animate({opacity:'1'});
        }
    })
    );


});
```

Comment: Your 3rd last line with code (``})``) should be ``)`` and the one after that (``);``) should be ``});``, I think

Comment: Is this what you want? http://testnaman.neocities.org/quicktest7.html

Comment: create jsfiddle fast

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/b21jwx44/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for focus events. Just give your element an initial opacity of 0:

**CSS**

```
.fdw-background {opacity: 0;}
```

and stop running animations before triggering a new one to prevent flicker like so:

**JS**

```
$('.fdw-background').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({opacity:'1'});
    },
    function () {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({opacity:'0'});
    }
);
```

[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/j6jm0nvn/2/). --------- [jQuery.fn.stop() here](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)